# How to make config changes take effect in Solr 7.3

Tags: solr

We are using solr.SynonymFilterFactory with synonyms.txt in Solr during ***querying***. I realized that there is an error in synonyms.txt, corrected it and uploaded the new file. I can see the modified synonyms.txt from Admin. But it looks like the queries are still using the old synonyms.txt. I am executing test queries from Admin with debugQuery=true and can see the synonyms getting used. How can this be fixed? It is a production environment with 3 nodes using zookeeper for management.

Comment: is it possible to restart the service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to reload your core for the changes to take effect.

In a single-node Solr you can do that from the Admin page: go to Core Admin, select your core, and hit Reload. This will slow down some queries but it shouldn't drop queries or connections.

You can also reload the core via the API:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=your-core'
```

I am not sure how this works on an environment with 3 nodes, though.

Comment: I think reload collection will work. 
/admin/collections?action=RELOAD&name=name